# Is there a command-line command to list, read, and delete Gnome notifications?

Tags: command-line, gnome

Is there a command-line command to list, read, and delete Gnome notifications? Something like:

```shellsession
$ gnome-notifications --list
1. [datetime-1] [program-1] Blah blah. 
2. [datetime-2] [program-2] Jibber jabber.

$ gnome-notifications --read 1
[datetime-1] [program-1] Blah blah.
Body:
Kishkush balabush shtuyot baleben,
istra balagina kish kish karyah.

$ gnome-notifications --delete 1
Deleted notification 1.
```

Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 2):

Notification services implement [the Desktop Notifications Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/notification-spec/notification-spec-latest.html), but that doesn’t provide [any command to list notifications](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/notification-spec/notification-spec-latest.html#commands).

To implement something like what you‘re after, following the specification, you’d have to intercept notifications and store them yourself. You would then be able to list them, and close them. See [this Ask Ubuntu Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/q/89279/412264) for details; I haven’t tried the scripts shown there so I won’t include code here for now.

Comment: Here on Ubuntu 22.04, I find the saved ones in `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/notifications`. It might also be possible to ask gnome-shell nicely for the new ones it has recorded since (assuming that's what the OP means).

Comment: Yup, I only looked into the spec, but actual implementations might well have the necessary features.